# Use Query Parameters in Lambda to retrieve filtered records from DynamoDB (Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Hi i am trying to pass my query parameter from my API URL to the query of the dynamoDB.

in this case it is id,
what i was hoping was to pass it into the key value to retreive a single record from Dynamo DB however it fails with event not defined.

also i get no response back , any thought on how to go by this.

compilation below is in python.

```
import boto3
import json
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Contacts')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('event:', json.dumps(event))

input = int(event['queryStringParameters']['id'])
    
response = table.get_item(
Key={"id": id })
item = response['Item']
return(item)
print(input)
```

Comment: do you have some example entries from you table Contacts?

Comment: id email 
10 bradley@test.com

Comment: What is your `event` and the exact error message?

Comment: Please fix your code indentation. If you think it's correct, then that's your first problem.

Comment: should this be Key={"id": input } -- you are creating input = , not id = from the event